# Capturing dots in magrittr pipe

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation, tidyverse, magrittr

Say we have a function

```
my_fun <- function(...) {
  substitute(list(...))[-1] %>%
    sapply(deparse)
}
```

This behaves as expected:

```
> my_fun(iris, mtcars)
[1] "iris"   "mtcars"
```

But this does not:

```
> iris %>% my_fun(mtcars)
[1] "."      "mtcars"
```

How do I modify my function to take care of this?

Comment: @MrFlick dupe indeed, thanks!